# How to get Groups in a Hub child class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms, signalr

I'm building an ASP Web form multiplayers game platform using SignalR to update the games fields.

I have `GameHub` that handle the new player connection:

```
[HubName("GameHub")]
public class GameHub : Hub
{
    static protected IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GameHub>();
    static public Dictionary<string, string> connectionIds_sessions = new Dictionary<string, string>();//connectionId and sessionId

    public void JoinGroup(string sessionId)
    {
        //this is called when the page is opened
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        connectionIds_sessions.Add(connectionId, sessionId);

        Groups.Add(connectionId, sessionId);
    }
}
```

And I have a child class for each games. For example `ThisHub`:

```
[HubName("TrisHub")]
public class TrisHub : GameHub
{
    public void SendTrisUpdates(string sessionId, TrisSession tris)
    {
        Clients.Group(sessionId).getUpdates(tris);//here I receive System.NullReferenceException.
    }
}
```

I can't send things at the group created from the mother class GameHub because there aren't.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, then your code won't work.

That's because you have a two different hubs and, therefore, two different pulls of connections.

When you call `JoinGroup` method in first time - you create a new group of connections, but only for `GameHub`.

And when you call `SendTrisUpdates` method it tries to found group which wasn't created for `TrisHub`. And then you call the method on group which isn't exist (equal `null`) and that's why you get an error.

To fix that, try to **combine your hubs into one** to make them have the same connections/groups.

Comment: so can't I have a mother class Hub?

Comment: you can. but they will be independent of each other (own connections, own groups etc).